# Como enviar 200 emails (não é newsletter) sem correr o risco de ir para spam list?

Tags: php, email, spam

Todos os meses enviamos 200/300 emails feitos à mão com um texto variável  para os clientes do mês (não é newsletter). Via PHP consigo fazer com que o texto seja dinâmico, e enviar automaticamente, mas o problema é enviar 200 emails sem que o domínio vá parar numa spam list... Alguma ideia de como fazer isto?

Comment: Use um serviço próprio para isso. O [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com), por exemplo, permite até 12k emails grátis por mês.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Envie os emails autenticados que não terá problema. Num serviço pequeno que administro envia-se mais de 80 mil emails por dia há mais de 10 anos e nunca caiu em spamlist. Eventualmente poderá ter problema referente a dns reverso, cabeçalhos dos emails e definições de dns. Mas são coisas relativamente simples de resolver. E também, evite enviar para quem não autoriza o recebimento, pois quando faz isso a pessoa que recebe normalmente denuncia e assim vai sujando o dominio até que ele caia nas bases de dados pública de spammers. Aí nesse ponto  terá uma certa dificuldade em pedir a remoção.

Deve-se tomar cuidado também que não basta apenas enviar autenticado. Precisa também certificar-se dos limites e normas do ambiente, o servidor onde o script será executado. Normalmente hospedagem compartilhada detecta execuções longas e as bloqueia. Outros permitem execuções contínuas, porém detectam envio de emails e impoem um limite de 100 a 400 emails diários ou mensal. Enfim, deve consultar as normas do seu provedor de hospedagem.

Outra observação é o servidor do email que será usado para autenticar os envios. Deve-se também observar os limites desse servidor de emails. O gmail por exemplo, tem um limite de 400 emails por dia, mas esse limite varia com o tipo da conta usada.

Resumindo:

```
1. Verifique as normas e limites do servidor de hospedagem
2. Verifique as normas e limites do servidor do email usado para autenticar
3. Verifique configurações de DNS reverso tanto para IPV4 quanto para IPV6
4. Não camufle o domínio do email que está enviando. seja o mais transparente possível
```

O ponto negativo de envio autenticado é a demora nos envios. Pois cada envio necessita de uma autenticação. É possível enviar emails legítimos sem cair nas spamlists, usando a função nativa [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), sem autenticação. Mas para isso o servidor deve estar bem configurado. O importante é que o servidor que envia possa ser reconhecido e "auditorado" remotamente em relação a sua identidade. Nesse caso, as verificações são feitas pelas configurações de DNS. Portanto, evite enviar de um servidor que não possua um domínio DNS. Pode ser usado um subdomínio, por exemplo.

Contudo, o volume que deseja enviar é pequeno. É possível executar tudo em menos de 1 segundo mesmo autenticado. Para isso precisará de técnicas de execução assíncrona.

Comment: tem ideia de como posso autenticar os emails ? eu uso normalmente o php para enviar os emails

Comment: Com o próprio PHP poderá enviar autenticado. Recomenda-se bibliotecas populares como PHPMailer, SwiftMailer, dentre outros. Particularmente prefiro o SwiftMailer. Há também outros meios usando a própria função nativa mail(), sem uso de bibliotecas terceiras, mas é um pouco mais complicado quando está rodando num servidor de hospedagem compartilhado sem acesso a configurações administrativas avançadas.